# scala template function vs forSome

Tags: scala, parameterized-types

I am experimenting with existential types.

I was playing with a function that expects a sequence where the elements of that seq are all the same type. I had ..

```
def bar[X](as: Seq[A[X]]) = true
```

Where ...

```
// parametised type to use in the question
trait A[T]
```

I then came across the "forSome" syntax and found I could achieve the same constraint with it.

I wrote the following for comparison purposes ...

```
// useful types 
trait A[T]
class AI extends A[Int]
class AS extends A[String]

// define two functions that both have the same constraint.
// ie the arg must be a Sequence with all elements of the same parameterised type

def foo(as: Seq[A[X]] forSome { type X }) = true

def bar[X](as: Seq[A[X]]) = true

// these compile because all the elements are the same type (AI)
foo(Seq(new AI, new AI))
bar(Seq(new AI, new AI))

// both these fail compilation as expected because 
// the X param of X[A] is different (AS vs AI)
foo(Seq(new AI, new AS))
bar(Seq(new AI, new AS))
```

What I am trying to understand is - am I missing something? 
What is the benefit of one signature over the other.

One obvious diff is that the compilation errors are different.

```
scala> foo(Seq(new AI, new AS))
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[A[_ >: String with Int]]
 required: Seq[A[X]] forSome { type X }

              foo(Seq(new AI, new AS))
                     ^

scala> bar(Seq(new AI, new AS))
<console>:12: error: no type parameters for method bar: (as: Seq[A[X]])Boolean e
xist so that it can be applied to arguments (Seq[A[_ >: String with Int]])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Seq[A[_ >: String with Int]]
 required: Seq[A[?X]]
              bar(Seq(new AI, new AS))
              ^
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[A[_ >: String with Int]]
 required: Seq[A[X]]
              bar(Seq(new AI, new AS))
                     ^

scala>
```

Comment: The scope of the `forSome` is important. Did you try `Seq[A[X] forSome { type X }]`? One possibly useful way to think about existential types and `forSome` is to think of it as a pair of a type and a value of that type. So a value of type `sometype forSome { type A }` is a pair of the type `A` along with some value whose type can depend on `A`. If you want a heterogeneous list, you need that pair to vary at each element in the `Seq`, and your version has a single `A` for the entire `Seq`.

Comment: To take it a step further, if you think of existentials as pairs with types, and universals (your `bar[X]` generic) as functions with types, your `foo` and `bar` types are isomorphic, by currying/uncurrying. This relationship is a lot clearer in a language with dependent types like Agda, but if you squint hard enough you might see it in Scala too.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in `foo` you may not refer to type `X`, whereas in `bar` you can:

```
// fails
def foo(as: Seq[A[X]] forSome { type X }) = Set.empty[X]

// btw the same:
def foo(as: Seq[A[_]]) = Set.empty[???]  // <-- what would you put here?

// OK
def bar[X](as: Seq[A[X]]) = Set.empty[X]
```